# Regex to get all instances of two consecutive digits within string

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex that extracts all instances of two consecutive digits (surrounded by non-digits or by the end of the string) from a string. The regex must work in PHP.

Examples:

```
string > extraction

'aaa123aaa' > {}
'aaa12aaa' > { 12 }
'aa3456aaa12aa' > { 12 }
'aa12aaa3456aa78aaa' > { 12, 78 }
'aaa12aaa12a' > { 12, 12 }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with look-arounds:

```
(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yxWMVq/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<!\d)`: Lookabehind to assert that we don't have a digit at previous position
- `\d{2}`: Match 2 digits
- `(?!\d)`: Lookahead to assert that we don't have a digit at next position

Comment: of course, look-arounds! Hadn't used regex's for a while and I forgot about them :) Thanks!

Comment: Your regex matches digits at the end of a string

Comment: Yes because OP wrote: `all instances of two consecutive digits (surrounded by non-digits or by the end of the string)`